# Open Main Page of Doxygen Documentation with CMake

Tags: cmake, documentation, doxygen

I have a project where I use Google Tests. I have the following CMake file in the root directory:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER gcc)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2 FATAL_ERROR)
project(PROJECT)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

set(SOURCES src/a.cpp src/b.cpp)

set(TESTSOURCES test/tests.cpp src/a.cpp src/br.cpp)

set(HEADERS src/a.h src/b.h src/c.h src/c.h)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${MAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(CURL REQUIRED)

# Locate GTest
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC)
    add_definitions(-Wall -Werror -lcurl)
endif(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC)

add_executable(tests ${TESTSOURCES} ${HEADERS} )

target_link_libraries(beergame-tests curl Qt5::Widgets ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} pthread)
```

For now, I have not added anything about the documentation into the CMakeLists.txt. To generate documentation, I just use `doxygen config-file`, which creates html/latex documentation in my latex folder. However, it doesn't really open the documentation and its main page.

How can I edit my CMakeLists.txt in such a way that it automatically opens the documentation and with what command?

To run the `tests.cpp`, I do this:

```
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

Comment: Do you also want CMake to run Doxygen? There will be nothing to open when CMake completes, because you then have to *generate* the documentation.

Comment: Yup, I want CMake to run Doxygen but I don't get what you mean by "nothing to open"? @squareskittles Is there no way to automatically open the main page of a doxygen documentation?

Comment: It wasn't clear if you intended to leave the `doxygen` command outside of CMake. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build and open the Doxygen documentation *before* CMake completes, you can use [`execute_process()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html) to build it during the CMake configuration stage. You can call `firefox <path-to-html>/index.html` (or some other browser) as a separate `COMMAND` to open the documentation after it builds.

```
find_package(Doxygen)
if(DOXYGEN_FOUND)
    execute_process(
        COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} config-file.doxygen
        COMMAND firefox ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc/html/index.html
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        COMMENT "Generating and opening documentation for project: tests"
    )
endif()
```

Note, on Windows 10, you may not need to specify the browser to use; simply listing the `index.html` file after `COMMAND` will open it in the default browser.

If you plan on making your Doxygen build into a separate **target**, you can do something similar using [`add_custom_target()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html):

```
find_package(Doxygen)
if(DOXYGEN_FOUND)
    add_custom_target(tests-Documentation
        COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} config-file.doxygen
        COMMAND firefox ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc/html/index.html
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        COMMENT "Generating documentation for project: tests"
        VERBATIM
    )
endif()
```

Comment: The config file was initially in the root directory but I tried adding it in the build folder too. Didn't work.

Comment: @FelicitySmith Yes, the responses I gave assume your Doxygen successfully generates the documentation, and places it in a folder `doc` as a sibling to the `.doxygen` config file itself. But you can change the paths as necessary to match your configuration.

Comment: @FelicitySmith It also assumes that the Doxygen config file (and the generated `doc` folder) is in a **source** directory, not a **build** directory. But again, this is all configurable, so you can just modify the paths to fit your setup.