# CMake for Doxygen

Tags: cmake, doxygen

I am trying to use CMake for Doxygen generated documentation. This is what my CMakeList.txt looks like:

```
if (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
    # set input and output files
    set(DOXYGEN_IN ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/config-file)
    set(DOXYGEN_OUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}doc)

    # request to configure the file
    configure_file(${DOXYGEN_IN} ${DOXYGEN_OUT} @ONLY)
    message("Doxygen build started")

    # note the option ALL which allows to build the docs together with the application
    add_custom_target( doc_doxygen ALL
        COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${DOXYGEN_OUT}
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
        COMMENT "Generating API documentation with Doxygen"
        VERBATIM )
else (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
  message("Doxygen need to be installed to generate the doxygen documentation")
endif (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
```

Upon running `make` , I get these errors:

```
Doxygen build started
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/newproject/build
[  5%] Generating API documentation with Doxygen
warning: tag INPUT: input source `doc/mainpage.txt' does not exist
warning: tag INPUT: input source `src/player.cpp' does not exist
warning: tag INPUT: input source `src/player.h' does not exist
warning: tag INPUT: input source `test/tests-mainfunctionality-v2.cpp' does not exist
error: tag OUTPUT_DIRECTORY: Output directory `doc' does not exist and cannot be created
Exiting...
CMakeFiles/doc_doxygen.dir/build.make:57: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/doc_doxygen' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/doc_doxygen] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/doc_doxygen.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/doc_doxygen.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

even though these files do exist. Is there something wrong with the paths I am using?

Comment: Parameter `WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` implies that `doxygen` executable will be called from the **build** directory. So `src/player.cpp` cannot be accessed from that directory.

Comment: Ah got it! @Tsyvarev is there any way I can directly open the index.html file from some command in the CMakeLists?

Comment: @FSJ For opening the generated documentation (e.g. `index.html`) using CMake, see the response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60856995/3987854).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to run Doxygen from your CMake binary directory (`build`), you will have to modify your Doxygen configuration file to include the correct relative paths:

```
INPUT = ../doc/mainpage.txt \
        ../src/player.cpp \
        ../src/player.h \
        ../test/tests-mainfunctionality-v2.cpp
```

Also, your use of the `DOXYGEN_OUT` looks a bit odd, as it is currently set to something *outside* the binary directory. This variable should specify a file name, in order for your `configure_file()` and custom target commands to work correctly. Perhaps, try renaming it to something like this:

```
# check if Doxygen is installed
find_package(Doxygen)
if (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
    # set input and output files
    set(DOXYGEN_IN ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/config-file)
    set(DOXYGEN_OUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/config-file.doxygen)

    # request to configure the file
    configure_file(${DOXYGEN_IN} ${DOXYGEN_OUT} @ONLY)
    message("Doxygen build started")

    # note the option ALL which allows to build the docs together with the application
    add_custom_target( doc_doxygen ALL
        COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${DOXYGEN_OUT}
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
        COMMENT "Generating API documentation with Doxygen"
        VERBATIM )
else (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
  message("Doxygen need to be installed to generate the doxygen documentation")
endif (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
```

Comment: I wrote /doc here ```set(DOXYGEN_OUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/config-file.doxygen)``` assuming that this is supposed to be the location where the documentation will be placed after the make. Isn't that so? Also, currently when I run make, it works fine but for some reason an additional ```build...``` folder gets generated. Any idea why?

Comment: @FSJ No, when you run `doxygen`, you need to provide it a config file. So when you run `COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${DOXYGEN_OUT}` in your custom target, `${DOXYGEN_OUT}` needs to be the config file. You specify *where* to place the generated documentation inside the config file itself. Look for the `OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` variable in the Doxygen config file, and you can set it to `../doc` or `doc` in your case.

Comment: Then what exactly is the difference between ```/config-file``` and ```config-file.doxygen```. For now, I only have one config-file in my root which actually creates the documentation.

Comment: You use `configure_file()` to copy `config-file` from your root to your build directory, and the `@ONLY` argument *may* make modifications to this file. Since you copy the Doxygen config file to your *build* directory, it seems like you want to *run* Doxygen from that directory. I just renamed the copied file to `config-file.doxygen` to make it more clear that it was a Doxygen config file.